# Ionic 2+ how long is the information saved in local storage?

Tags: ionic2, local-storage, ionic3, ionic-native, ionic-storage

I have a simple database that saves words and I'm trying to do as little database requests as possible in my app. I thought I would simply call a get request at the app startup and store all the words into the [Ionic local storage](https://ionicframework.com/docs/storage/) and then call them when needed.

I'm wondering how long the information stored in the local storage is being kept - does it clear when the user closes the app? Or does it clear when the phone is being restarted? Or is it kept till I clear it in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the user clears app data on android, all the data would go as well. Else it would remain till you call the storage's "clear" function.

Answer (score 0):

when you are clear ionic local storage `this.storage.clear();` and restart your app your data is loss